# Clustering: Error for "Lose" its Member During Initial. Possible?

Tags: matlab, cluster-analysis, k-means

I'm working with k-means in MATLAB GUI. I have done with it. The program (GUI) works quite fine (in command window, it works perfectly). I don't know, sometimes the GUI is working, but sometimes the error appears suddenly. Here is the error message:

```
??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback

??? Error using ==> kmeans>batchUpdate at 436
Empty cluster created at iteration 1.

Error in ==> kmeans at 337
        converged = batchUpdate();

Error in ==> CalcRand at 4
[g c] = kmeans(data,k,'dist','SqEuclidean');

Error in ==> kmeansFIN2>Centroid_Callback at 203
    [g,c,y,clr]=CalcRand( data,k );

Error in ==> gui_mainfcn at 96
        feval(varargin{:});

Error in ==> kmeansFIN2 at 42
    gui_mainfcn(gui_State, varargin{:});

Error in ==>
@(hObject,eventdata)kmeansFIN2('Centroid_Callback',hObject,eventdata,guidata(hObject))


??? Error while evaluating uicontrol Callback
```

A little explanation: My GUI has 4 push buttons, they are Cluster, Show Centroid, Show the Graphic, Evaluate the Graphic. I could give my code here, but it is too long, so I just give a hint of my codes:

```
% CLUSTER (PUSH BUTTON)
[g c] = kmeans(cobat,k,'dist','SqEuclidean');
y = [cobat g]

% SHOW CENTROID (PUSH BUTTON)
c

% EVALUATE THE CLUSTER
[s,h]=silhouette(cobat,g,'SqEuclidean');

% SHOW THE GRAPHIC
%# show points and clusters (color-coded)
clr = lines(k);
figure, hold on
scatter3(cobat(:,1), cobat(:,2), cobat(:,3), 36, clr(g,:), 'Marker','.')
scatter3(c(:,1), c(:,2), c(:,3), 100, clr, 'Marker','o', 'LineWidth',3)
hold off
view(3), axis vis3d, box on, rotate3d on
xlabel('x'), ylabel('y'), zlabel('z')
```

According to the error, someone said that, "It is possible for a cluster to "lose" all of its members during the initial phase of clustering; that's just how the K-Means algorithm works. The usual reason why this happens is a bad choice of starting cluster centroids. The
'EmptyAction' parameter controls what steps are taken if it does happen, and the default is to error out." Is it right? Can someone explain me with trusted sources? And is there way to stay away from this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's possible that during the k-means algorithm one cluster can lose all its members. That can happen at any stage of the algorithm; however the most likely cause is that the initial cluster centroids were poorly chosen, and in that case it's likely to occur at an early stage of the algorithm.

MATLAB's `kmeans` algorithm has a parameter `EmptyAction` that specifies what should be done in this case. `EmptyAction` can be set to `error` (default), `drop` (in which case the cluster is dropped and the corresponding return values are set to NaN) or `singleton` (in which case a new cluster is created as a single point that is furthest from its centroid).

Choosing either `drop` or `singleton` should allow the algorithm to proceed to completion, but you should still be aware that it may be well be the case that the initial centroids were poorly chosen, in which case you should try to address that.

[Documentation for kmeans](http://www.mathworks.com/help/stats/kmeans.html)

Comment: If I was receiving this error, I would try to choose better initial centroids.

Comment: I'm thinking about that. But I'm getting confused of the code because the number of clusters (2-7) is choosen by user. So, we never know how many cluster would it be, we never know how many edit-texts (GUI) to put. Any idea? :)

Answer (score 1):

As @SamRoberts already put it: yes, clusters in k-means can become empty. This probably won't happen in your average synthetic data set, but in real data it *can* happen; in particular when you use data that is discrete or worse: binary.

There are multiple ways of handling this, for example you may decide to just always keep the last point in the cluster that was there before. Or restart with a new cluster. or reduce k.